# Node Js API - Creating GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am creating my first API with nodejs and MongoDB and I would like to create a GET request like "localhost: 3050 / user / name"..
so I build this :

```
server.get('/user/:name',UserController.read);
```

...

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({

    name: String,
    email: String,
    compagny: String,


},{collection: "USER_COLLEC"});

const User = mongoose.model('user',UserSchema);
```

...

```
read (req,res) {
        const name= req.body.name;
        User.find({name : name}).then( (user) => {
            res.send({user});
        })
    }
```

this code return me :

```
{
    "user": []
}
```

Comment: What is `User`? I'm guessing it is some sort of database API. What does the documentation for that API say about searching on other fields?

Comment: I've reedited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using route parameters ,req.params will return parameters in the matched route
use `const  name=req.params.name` instead of `const name= req.body.name;`